# Different versions of proto files

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I had a proto like this:

```
message Person {
  required string name = 1;
  required int32 id = 2;
  optional string email = 3;
}
```

Now i have to add another field to it so it looks like this:

```
message Person {
  required string name = 1;
  required int32 id = 2;
  optional string email = 3;
  optional string phone = 4;
}
```

If i now deserialize Persons that were serialized with the older version will the only difference be that hasPhone() will always be false? So assuming that phone will be set for all new persons i can actually distinguish if it is old/new version of proto by hasPhone being true/false?

Comment: Why did you quote me mid sentence? :) The start of it was "So assuming that phone will be set for all new persons...".

Comment: Sorry. It's been a long night :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is correct.

You can also use `getPhone()` and check if the string is empty, since the empty string is the default value for string-typed fields.